# Prepositional phrases as pseudo-nouns

Tags: prepositions

I’ve been searching about the usage of prepositional phrase as a pseudo-noun, and I’ve found that when it’s used as a subject, the frequency of the usage is like locational meaning > temporal meaning > the others(so rare). However, I can’t really see the coherence in other usage, as an object to verbs or prepositions.

I think the usage as an object to verbs is just like that as subjects, and that as an object to prepositions is more complicated and collocational problem. Can you enlighten me...?

Comment: Try giving some examples of prepositional phrases used as a verb’s subject and some examples of prepositional phrases used as a verb’s object so your question can be addressed concretely.

Comment: An example of PP used as a subject is like, “Through the wood” is the nearest way.                                                          and as a object is like, I’ll give you “until next morning”.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot.  Now what do you mean by “acceptance level orders”? Is that just jargon for relative frequency of usage, or is some other concept being invoked?

Comment: Thank you, it’s frequency of usage.

Comment: The only way to answer that question would be a statistical analysis based on data extracted from a program like, but more sophisticated, than Ngram. I cannot answer you. I suspect what you need is someone to point you at the relevant scholarly journals (if there are any). Sorry

Comment: It’s ok, thank you so much!